# Swift base 64 not encode to android images

Tags: mysql, swift, base64

I convert image to base64 string ,then upload them to MySQL with xcode and Swift ,but when download them in Json format with android studio get bad string64 error
I used whole the method in android such as URL safe and etc and in xcode used option raw zero
Would anyone help me with this
Thanx

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imgview.image = UIImage(named: "sexy")
    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"maddona")!
    let imageData:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

and this is the java fetch

```
 civ = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
String imageFetched = " this is the fetched string from json " byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(imageFetched.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE);
        civ.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
```

Comment: Please post the code that is giving you the issue.  As it stands, there is not enough information in your question to answer it.

Comment: Can you also add the error, and highlight exactly which line of code is generating the problem?

Comment: Unanswerable as lacking a [mcve].

Comment: URL safe base 64 uses `-` and `_` for characters 62 and 63 whereas the standard base 64 (which Cocoa does) uses `+` and `/`. Either don't use the `URL_SAFE` option or replace the `+` and `/` characters with `-` and `_`, respectively, before sending it. It depends upon how you're sending this.